# Perl - Finding sets of similar association

Tags: perl

I have the following data set

```
 A       C
 A       S
 B       F
 B       Q
 C       A
 C       I
 D       K
 E       Y
 F       B
 F       R
 I       Y
 K       P
```

Each value in the first column has an associated value in the second column. The value "A" in row 1 has the associated value "C". In the second row, the value "A" has the value "S" associated.

Using Perl, I would like to find the set of all associated values. Using the rules above, I would get the sets (ACEISY), (BFQR) and (DKP).

I'm looking for suggestions on the algorithm or examples of how you would tackle this problem. I'm not sure if a hash table would be the proper data structure to employ for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my implementation:

```
while<INPUT>{
    my ($c1, $c2) = split;
    my %clusterhash = ();
    if (exists $clusterhash{$c1}){
        if (exists $clusterhash{$c1}{$c2}){
            #do nothing
        }
        else {
            $clusterhash{$c1}{$c2} = $c2;
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach my $key ( keys %clusterhash ) {
            if (exists $clusterhash{$key}{$c1}{
                $clusterhash{$c1}{$key} = $key;
            }
        }
        $clusterhash{$c1}{$c2} = $c2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived the sets `(ACEISY), (BFQR) and (DKP)` using the logic you mentioned?

Comment: For the first set - In row 1, A is associated with C. In row 2, A is associated with S. In row 6, C is associated with I. In row 11, I is associated with Y. In row 8, E is associated with Y. Therefore the set is (ACEISY).

Comment: Can't see relation in `AC AS CI IY EY => ACEISY`

Comment: If each letter is an area, then (ACEISY) = A∪C∪E∪I∪S∪Y

Comment: A and C share a set; A and S share a set; C and I share a set; I and Y share a set; E and Y share a set. None of them share a set with any more variables, thus there is a set containing exactly A, C, E, I, S and Y.

Answer (score 5):

Your data set can be viewed as a directed graph which is possibly disconnected. It seems to me you want the node set for each weakly connected subgraph. Writing this yourself isn't difficult:

- We view the graph as undirected.
- We store the edges in a hash, so that an entry `$edge{$a}{$b}` is a directed edge from vertex `$a` to `$b`.
- Now all we need is an iterative search, deleting all visited edges as we go.

Example code:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature qw/say/;

# build the graph
my %edge;
while (<>) {
  my ($from, $to) = split;
  $edge{$from}{$to} = $edge{$to}{$from} = undef;
}

while (my ($start) = keys %edge) {
  my @seen  = ($start);
  my @stack = ($start);

  while (@stack) {
    my $vertex = pop @stack;

    # delete edges from and to this vertex
    # NB: any connections to seen vertices are already removed.
    my @reachable = keys %{ delete($edge{$vertex}) // {} };
    delete $edge{$_}{$vertex} for @reachable;

    # mark new vertices as seen, and enqueue them
    push @seen, @reachable;
    push @stack, @reachable;
  }

  my $nodes = join ', ', sort @seen;
  say "node set: {$nodes}";
}
```

Output for your data:

```
node set: {B, F, Q, R}
node set: {D, K, P}
node set: {A, C, E, I, S, Y}
```

This algorithm is already fairly optimal, and runs in *O*(*n* · *k*) time and space (where *k* is the average number of neighbors).

Of course, there already is a module that implements graph algorithms. Unsuprisingly, it is called [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph). The above code is equivalent to:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature qw/say/;
use Graph;

my $graph = Graph::Undirected->new;
while (<>) {
  my ($from, $to) = split;
  $graph->add_edge($from, $to);
}

for my $nodes_array ($graph->connected_components) {
  my $nodes = join ', ', sort @$nodes_array;
  say "node set: {$nodes}";
}
```

It is possible to perform these calculations in less memory and possibly less time by keeping track of the connected components as we build the graph. For this, we have a hash that maps vertices to their subgraphs.

1. If an both vertices of an edge are unknown, they create a new subgraph.
2. If exactly one vertex is known, the other node maps to the subgraph of the first node, and is listed there as a member.
3. If both vertices are known, then

   1. If they point to the same subgraph, nothing happens.
   2. If they point to different subgraphs, all entries are updated to point to the same subgraph which now contains the combined nodes of the previous subgraphs.

The code:

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature qw/say/;

my %subgraph_by_id;
my %subgraph_by_vertex;
while(<>) {
  my ($x, $y) = split;
  # case 1:
  # If an both vertices of an edge are unknown, they create a new subgraph.
  if (not exists $subgraph_by_vertex{$x} and not exists $subgraph_by_vertex{$y}) {
    my $new = [$x, $y];
    $subgraph_by_id{0+ $new} = $new;
    $subgraph_by_vertex{$_} = $new for $x, $y;
  }
  # case 2:
  # If exactly one vertex is known, the other node maps to the subgraph of the
  # first node, and is listed there as a member.
  elsif (not exists $subgraph_by_vertex{$x} or not exists $subgraph_by_vertex{$y}) {
    my ($known, $unknown) = (exists $subgraph_by_vertex{$x}) ? ($x, $y) : ($y, $x);
    my $subgraph = $subgraph_by_vertex{$unknown} = $subgraph_by_vertex{$known};
    push @$subgraph, $unknown;
  }
  # case 3:
  # both vertices are known. If they point to different subgraphs, all entries
  # are updated to point to the same subgraph which now contains the combined
  # nodes of the previous subgraphs.
  # Except all that copying would make for a horrible worst case.
  # Instead, we just add a reference to the smaller list, flattening it later.
  else {
    my $prev_x = $subgraph_by_vertex{$x};
    my $prev_y = $subgraph_by_vertex{$y};
    # don't test for inequality directly to allow subgraph nesting
    if ($subgraph_by_id{0+ $prev_x} != $subgraph_by_id{0+ $prev_y}) {
      my ($new, $old) = (@$prev_x > @$prev_y) ? ($prev_x, $prev_y) : ($prev_y, $prev_x);
      push @$new, $old;
      # $old not needed on top level any longer – associate it with $new by id
      $subgraph_by_id{0+ $old} = 0+ $new;
    }
  }
}

# skip symbolic IDs
for my $nodes_array (grep ref, values %subgraph_by_id) {
  my $nodes = join ', ', flatten($nodes_array);
  say "node set: {$nodes}";
}

sub flatten {
  return map { ref $_ ? flatten($_) : $_ } @{ shift() };
}
```

This uses only *O*(*n*) space and time, using a lot of awkward tricks. During the building of the subgraphs, I do not merge two connected subgraphs and rather defer that until later. Otherwise, an edge case (a balanced tree built bottom up – for each non-leaf node, half of the tree would be copied) could maybe need exponential time – I didn't do a full analysis. The `0+` “venus” pseudooperator numifies its argument, used here to obtain IDs for array references.

Comment: Sweet! The 3rd algorithm should run in linear space and time.

Comment: @user2674514 The first problem could mean you are running an ancient perl (older than Perl5 v10.0). What is your exact version? You can work around of this by swapping `//` for `||`, removing `use feature "say"`, and swapping `say ...` for `print ..., "\n"`. I only tested my code with your example input, so I don't know why it might hang for other input. If you could provide a larger data set (e.g. via some paste site) I might be able to do some better performance debugging. However, it is quite possible the 1st solution is performant enough for your needs.

Comment: I've tested your 3rd algorithm. In cases where the value of col 2 occurs twice or more for a different value in col 1 (row 1 and 4), it captures the 1st occurance but misses any preceding. Therefore in the example data set below, row 4 is not captured.

    `A       C`
    `A       S`
    `B       F`
    `D       C`

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm running version 5.8.8 and the defined-or operator // does not work for me. Please disregard my previous comment about your 3rd code set not working - It does work but see my comment above on how it misses some rows.

Comment: I provided my real data set here: [link](http://goo.gl/HDxYvL). Note that my true data set contains numbers instead of characters (ABCDEF). I used characters as an example for my initial problem. In my true data set the numbers reflect positional information for two linear strings. The cluster column is clustering the positions by regions. What i refer as col1 and col2 in my initial example is represented by start1 and start2 in my real data set. Ultimately I'm trying to find multiple repeat regions occurring in both strings. These repeat regions can vary in len, hence the difference in start.

Comment: @user2674514 I could not reproduce your problems :( When I run the `A C` `A S` `B F` `D C` data I get the two clusters `B F` and `A C D S`, which is the same as solution #1. When I run your real data (using only columns 2 and 4), I get 29 clusters which I verified with solution #1 and by grepping the resulting sets in the file.

Answer (score 1):

This was not really supposed to become an answer but a comment but it grew too Long and would not fit into the comment field:

Is Speed any issue? As in, is there so many data that it might be a bad idea to Loop through it often? Because if Looping repeatadly is no Problem than a hash would be an easy solution: Take the first element of column 1 that is not yet in your hash; Add it to the hash as key with a new set number; iterate through all rows, adding all ist associated values to the hash as keys as well and with the same set number; If you added a new key in the last Iteration, do it again for those keys until you add no new keys; take the next element not yet in your hash and repeat with the next set index; 
Once there are no unassigned elements you have all your elements in a hash as keys with their set as value.
You might Need to Format it how you want it lastly.

edit: Okay if speed is an issue, how about scaling of the number of values instead of the number of rows?

Have a outer hash with set indizes as keys and inner hashes as values. Those inner hashes get elements as keys and "1" as values. Iterate through lines. In each line, check if the values are already a key in one or two of the inner hashes. If they are in different hashes, merge those hashes and delete one of the keys of the outer hash. If one is in one hash and the other is not, add the new value to the hash of the first one, if they are in the same hash, do nothing, if neither is any hash, create a new key for the outer hash and add both values into the corresponding inner hash.

If the inner hashs are likely to grow big or if there possibly are many sets, this may grow extremely slow. But if the set of possible values is small compared to the number of rows, this may be quite fast.

BEST EDIT:
I just had another idea. This one Looks at every row three times at most (more likely to be two times assuming random associations) what i suppose is reasonably fast but Needs more Memory.
Iterate through the lines with two big hashes. In each line you add cell2 to the Array stored in hash1 at the key cell1 and add cell1 to the Array stored in hash2 at the key cell2. Basically you read all the Information into those two hashes.. Now you take a random key of hash1 and add that key as well as all elemts in the correspoinding Array into whatever structure you want your final sets to be stored (i would assume as keys into a third hash with set number as value) and delete the key from hash1. Now you also look up all those elements as keys in hash2 and add everything in those Arrays to the set as well delete the keys from hash2. Now you take everything already added to the set as keys for hash1 and once again add everything in the Arrays to the set and so on. You have to Keep doing this until hash1 and hash2 both consecutively have nothing to add to the set. And then you take another random key and start the next set. Deleting all used keys guarantees you get nothing twice and you do not check the same row often. That is assuming that looking up if a key exists in a hash actually is as fast as i believe it is.

Comment: The number of rows can be significantly large (> 1 million). Speed and memory is always and issue. I'm just trying to figure out an efficient way to do this.

Comment: If the number of possible values is small compared to the number of rows, check my edit. If the number of values is big as well, i have no good idea.

Comment: New update that should be fast no matter what but uses more Memory.